# Order an Array of Rectangles by Size

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of rectangles and I want to order it in descending fashion by size. Then I want to select the top 10 and use it in another function that takes in an array of rectangles. Below is my code. However, I get the exeception  "At least one object must implement IComparable" when I convert back to an array. Can someone guide me.

```
Rectangle[] BoundingBoxes = GetRectangles(param1, param2);   
IEnumerable<Rectangle> BoundingBoxesSorted = BoundingBoxes.OrderByDescending(
                                                 item => item.Size).Take(10);

Rectangle[] BoundingBoxes10 = BoundingBoxesSorted.Cast<Rectangle>().ToArray();
```

Comment: What type is `BoundingBoxes` ?

Comment: Sid show all code that is relevant to the question that you are asking.. this will help in the many questions than others may have..show where and how BoundingBoxes is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because [`System.Drawing.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) (the type of [`Rectangle.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.size.aspx)) does not implement `IComparable`. That makes sense, since there's no *natural* ordering for a tuple of numbers such as `(Width, Height)`: would `(10, 5)` be less than `(7, 8)`?

Either select something that is comparable (e.g. just the `Width` or the area `Width * Height`), or pass a custom `IComparer` as second argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<Rectangle> BoundingBoxesSorted = 
                                   BoundingBoxes.OrderBy(r => r.Width * r.Height);
```

or you can define a custom comparer

```
var comparer = Comparer<Size>.Create((s1, s2) => 
                            (s1.Width * s1.Height).CompareTo(s2.Width * s2.Height));

IEnumerable<Rectangle> BoundingBoxesSorted = 
                                       BoundingBoxes.OrderBy(r => r.Size,comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order by Size because it is not comparable.  You may want to order by the area (width * height).

Try this:

```
var top10 = BoundingBoxes
   .OrderByDescending(b => b.Width * b.Height)
   .Take(10)
   .ToArray();
```

Note that you do not have to `Cast` because the enumeration is already dealing with `Rectangles`.

You could also extend `Rectangle` to have an `Area` property.

```
 public static class Extensions
 {
    public static int Area(this Rectangle r) 
    {
        return r.Width * r.Height;
    }
 }
```